# How does SVN merge and Update work?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

I am new in SVN and I am confounded !

consider I have checked out from  `/mybranch/trunk` and I have this files in directory :

```
index.php
style.css
```

and `index.php`'s content is :

```
<?php

function say(  )
{
     echo "Hello" ; 
}

$name = "Tom" ;

?>
```

While I am working in my working place I will edit this file like this :

```
#worikin place Edit 1 
<?php

function say( $name )
{
     echo "Hello" . $name  ; 
}

$name = "jerry" ;

say( $name )

?>
```

now if I commit , #worikin place Edit 1  will replace in   `/mybranch/trunk`   and its ok !

but if someone else had edited index.php and commited that , while I was editing  like this :

```
#another user commited index.php on `/mybranch/trunk`
<?php

function say( $name , $lname )
{
     echo "Hello" . $name .$lname  ; 
}

$name = "tom" ;
$lname = "max" ;

say( $name )

?>
```

now I have `#worikin place Edit 1`  in my working place , When I want to commit it what happens ?

if I want to update index.php what happens ? what is index.php content after update ?  what is SVN's strategy to merge differences between Working place file and branch file ?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Also, did you mean to change the case of the $name in the instance of someone else editing? should "tom" == "Tom"

Comment: @Intern87 this is not a homework question . I mean  what is SVN's strategy to merge differences between Working place file and branch file ?

Comment: if both branches came from the same working place file, and someone had edited (the same lines of code) and committed before you there will be a merge conflict and SVN will not auto merge for you.
SVN content after update would be the first person to commits changes until you have resolved the merge conflict.

Answer (score 1):

On commit, the server determines whether any of the affected files have been modified on later revisions. If that's not the case, commit completes successfully. Otherwise, it's aborted and you're asked to update your working copy.

When you update the working copy, the client determines whether any of the incoming files have been modified locally. If that's not the case, update completes successfully. Otherwise, it attempts to merge incoming changes into local file.

When trying to merge incoming changes, the client determines whether such changes can be cleanly inserted. If that's the case, merge completes successfully. Otherwise, you get a conflict which you need to fix manually.